# What triggers android chrome to show the "make page mobile-friendly" panel?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, mobile

When I load http://www.thinkloop.com/article/state-driven-routing-react-redux-selectors/ in android chrome, a panel appears at the bottom of the site asking if I would like to make the page mobile-friendly.

Clicking on that option changes very little on the page since it is already very mobile-friendly.

What triggers this question and how can I address the issues it thinks it detects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the viewport isn't defined in the sites meta tags. The browser doesn't know that the site has a responsive design and will attempt to set one if the prompt is clicked even if one is already defined.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Added: `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width">`

Additionally, google page speed insights tells the same: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thinkloop.com%2Farticle%2Fstate-driven-routing-react-redux-selectors%2F (well not anymore now that I fixed it)

Comment: Also a specific mobile check tool from google: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/?utm_source=psi&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=uxresults&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thinkloop.com%2Farticle%2Fstate-driven-routing-react-redux-selectors%2F